# GDAL.RasterizeLayer not ported to the C# bindings?

Tags: c#, gdal, ogr

I am trying to use the `OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.RasterizeLayer(…)` from *GDAL 1.9.2* and it requires some `SWIGTYPE` parameters:

```
OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.RasterizeLayer(
    OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset dataset,
    int bands,
    OSGeo.GDAL.SWIGTYPE_p_int band_list,
    OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer,
    OSGeo.GDAL.SWIGTYPE_p_void pfnTransformer,
    OSGeo.GDAL.SWIGTYPE_p_void pTransformArg,
    int burn_values,
    OSGeo.GDAL.SWIGTYPE_p_double burn_values_list,
    string[] options,
    OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate callback,
    string callback_data
);
```

Reading up on some old mails somewhere (*I've lost the link*) regarding ReadRaster and WriteRaster in the C# bindings, **Tamas Szekeres** states that methods requesting `SWIGTYPE` parameters, cannot be used (yet).

**Question:**
Does this mean that the RasterizeLayer method hasn’t been ported to the C# bindings or are there some clever way to utilise this method?

Answer (score 1):

SWIG Interface file [Operations.i](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/include/Operations.i) and generated files for csharp in gdal-1.9.1/swig/csharp/gdal/Gdal.cs says that they are available in GDAL C# bindings. Could you please tell what error exactly are you getting when performing rasterization.?

Comment: I have no idea about how to use the `SWIGTYPE` parameters, what to initialise them with and so on.

Comment: SWIGTYPE_p_int is an int array in c# and 
SWIGTYPE_p_double is double array. 
so for OSGeo.GDAL.SWIGTYPE_p_int band_list you can provide c# array of int[]
try this and see what error you are getting

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to initialize and what to provide one of the *SWIGTYPE* parameters with?

Comment: try C# int where it asks for SWIGTYPE_p_int. i dindt tried myself. Maybe there is a better solution. But there is no harm in trying this